# Selecting GLES version in Google Cardboard Android SDK

Tags: android, opengl-es, google-cardboard

How does the `CardboardView` class in the Google Cardboard SDK select which OpenGL ES version to use?  I was hoping that it literally inherited from `GlSurfaceView` so that I could use `setEGLContextClientVersion` as described [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html#setEGLContextClientVersion(int)), but it looks like that's not the case.

My goal is to select OpenGL ES 3.0 -- much of my existing rendering code is implemented on the native side and depends on that version.

Comment: Looks like instead of inheriting from ```GlSurfaceView```, it owns one which can be retrieved via the ```getGlSurfaceView``` method, which appears to be missing from the Cardboard SDK docs.  Remains to be seen whether setting the context client version is honored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cardboard SDK uses an OpenGL ES 2.0 compatible client.
Though this doesn't seem to be officially supported, my experience is that GL ES 3.0/3.1 can be used with such a context, provided that the phone actually supports ES 3.x. Which can be checked with this call:

```
String version = javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10.glGetString(
    GL10.GL_VERSION);
```

More detail at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html#version-check

That said, it looks like we should add proper support for using ES 3.x with the SDK, thanks for flagging this.

Comment: That page assumes you are creating the EGL context yourself, which will not be the case if you're getting a pre-made GLSurfaceView. The version info returned by the driver only indicates what it's capable of.

Comment: I don't think who created the context actually matters. Have you tried running ES 3.0 commands and does it fail on a phone that supports ES 3.0?

Comment: If the EGL context was created with an `EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION` of 1 or 2, I would expect GLES 3 functions to fail. It doesn't matter *who* created it, but *how* it was created does matter. Ideally Cardboard will be creating the context for 3 and falling back to 2 if not available, in which case a driver capability check will work, but I don't think that's guaranteed.

Comment: My experience is that GL ES 3.0 functions don't fail on a ES 2.0 context, provided the driver supports ES 3.0. 
But reading that doc again, it says "if you discover that the device supports a higher-level API version, you must destroy the minimum OpenGL ES context and create a new context with the higher available API version."
So what I said might work in practice but doesn't seem officially supported. Thanks for double-checking! I'll adjust my answer accordingly.

Comment: Was OpenGLES3 support for Cardboard ever added?